# How can I know where my server is located (physically speaking)?

Tags: whois, localization

I would like to know where my server is physically based. Is there tools that are available to get this informations (latitude/longitude) from command line (GNU/Linux) ?

Comment: is localizated a word?  and i don't know of any reliable methods to tell.  ask your host.

Comment: I've told you, you can have the server location when you transfer the funds. Any more stunts and I'll start pulling disks, understand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless it has a working GPS tracker, no you can't really. What you can do:

- lookup your IP (it offers you geographic data to whom it is issued and sometimes where it is approximately is located)
- ask you service provider

Comment: My problem was precisely about approximation... I will ask the provider.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your host. If they won't tell you, or if you don't trust them to provide a true answer, it's time to get a new host.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a virtual server then it may well be pointless finding this out as this may change. In fact your server may even be moving location several times a day as some virtual hosting suppliers use a 'follow the sun' system to reduce their power bills.

Comment: You're right cause I've already tried www.ripe.net to find it: ripe.net gives a main location, plus several minor locations.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it may be possible to work it out via your IPs from Ripe. www.ripe.net. You can also get a sense of where it is going from traceroutes if you suspect your server is hosts in the Asias, for example.

Comment: These tools are very interesting thanx...